# Custom Module custom block not loading the template in magento 2 admin

Tags: magento2

In the layout file the desired feature should be to call my custom Block but if I do that then the template doesn't load. You can check the line commented in the below layout file. The other line which does load the template is unable to communicate with the custom Block.

Could someone please help me with what I have done wrong it would be a great help. Also if any other code be required to provide please comment I will update the question.

The layout file    /app/code/Synlogics/PushNotification/view/adminhtml/layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <head>
            <title>
                Push Notification - Configuration
            </title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <referenceContainer name="content">
                <!--<block class="Synlogics\PushNotification\Block\PushNotification" name="pushnotification_index_index" template="Synlogics_PushNotification::config.phtml"/>-->
                <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" template="Synlogics_PushNotification::config.phtml"/>
            </referenceContainer>
        </body>
    </page>
```

the template file /app/code/Synlogics/PushNotification/view/adminhtml/templates

```
<?php 
$collection = $block->getApiDetailsCollection();
//echo $collection[0]->getAndroidApiKey();
?>
```

the controller /app/code/Synlogics/PushNotification/Controller/Adminhtml/Index

```
<?php
namespace Synlogics\PushNotification\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;
class Config extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action{
    /**
    * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
    */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Load the page defined in view/adminhtml/layout/notification_index_config.xml
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute() {

        return  $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

the block file /app/code/Synlogics/PushNotification/Block

```
<?php
namespace Synlogics\PushNotification\Block;


use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Synlogics\PushNotification\Model\Data;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;


class PushNotification extends Template
{
    protected $model;

    public function __construct(Context $context, Data $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
        parent::__construct($context);                
    }

    public function getApiDetailsCollection() {
        $loadmodel =  $model->load(1);
        $apiCollection = $loadmodel->getCollection()->getData();
        return $apiCollection;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your block following way:

```
<?php
namespace Synlogics\PushNotification\Block;


use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Synlogics\PushNotification\Model\Data;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;


class PushNotification extends Template
{
    protected $model;

    public function __construct(Context $context, Data $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
        parent::__construct($context);                
    }

    public function getApiDetailsCollection() {
        $apiCollection = $this->model->getCollection()->getData();
        return $apiCollection;
    }
}
```